# Blackberry component libraries

Tags: blackberry, libraries

Blackberry UI components look so poor after seeing the iPhone, Android and Windows Phone 7 platforms.

Are there any third-party UI component libraries for BlackBerry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Article [How to implement advanced BB UI](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Implement_advanced_buttons,_fields,_and_managers.html?nodeid=2406256&vernum=0) contains many ready-to-use components!